# Finding the last different position in an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

I have a vector `A` of dimension `1xn` composed of zeros and ones. I want a very efficient way to find the position `j` of the last element of `A` such that `A(j)~=A(n)`. If the elements of `A` are all equal then the code should return `n`.

Example:

If `A=[1 0 1 1 1]`, I should get `2`.
If `A=[0 0 0 0 0]`, I should get `5`.
If `A=[1 0 0 0 0]`, I should get `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one line, just for the fun of it:

```
result = min([find(A~=A(end),1,'last') numel(A)]);
```

Comment: Does it work also with `A` matrix, applied row by row?

Comment: @user3285148 No, it doesn't. Do you need that? The question says a vector

Comment: Vector is OK. I'll post another question applied to a matrix. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for accepting, but consider Sardar Usama's answer, which is clearer. The only "advantage" of this one is that it uses one line, but it's hacier and less readable

Comment: For matrix `A`, if I understand correctly, try this: `[~, ind] = max(bsxfun(@ne, flip(A,2), A(:,end)),[],2); ind = size(A,2)-ind+1;`

Comment: Thanks Luis, But I consider your answer to be better. I would also have selected your answer if I had asked the same question

Comment: @SardarUsama I gave to your answer +1. I chose Luis' answer because I like 1 line solutions, as my real code is very long.

Answer (score 2):

Use `find` with the [`last`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html#budqvnh-1) flag. Add a condition if `find` results in an empty matrix.

```
req= find(A~=A(end),1,'last');
if isempty(req) req=length(A); end
```